# How to block some urls with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I 'm trying to make my own chrome extension
to block the "seen" and "typing" status of facebook.
But it seems my way doesnt work

Can someone help me find my error?

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Block Seen Typing",
    "description": "Block Seen",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
                    "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
{
    urls: [
        "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/typ.php", "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/mark_seen.php", "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php"                    // here you put the URL that you want to block.
    ],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
},
["blocking"]);
```

Generaly i want to know how to block any webrequest that i want.

Comment: Have you looked at the console in the background page? You should have received an error message that showed that the parameters of `addListener` are bad, and after fixing that, that the [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) in `urls` are incorrect.

Comment: @RobW changed the url's. In console i get no error.. but still it is showing the "seen" status

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to actually include any code for a listener. Try something like this

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(d){
  return {cancel:true};
},{urls:["https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/typ.php",
         "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/mark_seen.php",
         "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php"]},
  ["blocking"]);
```

Comment: @SteliosM. You'll want to double check if the requests are actually being canceled. You can find them under the network tab in the dev tools. My code was just an example of where the function goes and how to cancel a request, I haven't tested it on FB or anything.

Comment: @SteliosM. For what you are trying to do, this should work given that FB only sends calls to those urls for it to mark stuff as read and it is actually canceling the requests.

Comment: altough other extensions are working, mine is not working. And it has no errors in console but either any message that it blocks these urls "webrequest post"